# Pass a sheet name to LastRow function

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a sheet name to this function to be passed from other parts of the code where the function is called?  There has to be a way other than making sure the sheet I want to evaluate is 'selected' prior to calling the function.

```
Function LastRow()

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, including an optional parameter to focus on a specific column if needed

```
Function LastRow(targetSheet as Worksheet, _
                 Optional targetCol as String = "A")
    With targetSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).row
    End With    
End Function
```

Comment: can i do something like this to capture the row to be evaluated as well?`Function LastRow(targetSheet As Worksheet, targetRow As Range)

    With targetSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, targetRow).End(xlUp).row
    End With

End Function`

Comment: Use an `Optional` parameter that defaults to "A". Then you can use the `LastRow` function with or without the column letter.